# How is API activity handled when an application is in the middle of another operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, api

Say my application is performing an operation (counting pi to 1000th decimal place). During this time another application accesses my API (REST or SOAP does it matter?) and requests data.

Will they be left hanging or does the server/jvm handle this request on a different thread (even if my application is single threaded).

I've been told different things

edit: I am running this in a web container. Currently Jetty but will probably need to move to Tomcat at least.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web server will spawn new threads (it will actually more likely use a thread within its pool, and you *could* configure it differently, but the default behavior is likely to use a pool of threads) for each request, so your callers will not be left hanging (unless you're over your server's capacity).

Your code needs to be thread safe to handle multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you expand on thread safety? Yes a majority of the threads will be accessing a few key variables. Integers which will change irregularly. Quite a simple transaction

Comment: If your services have state to them, then multiple threads accessing them at the same may have issues if the code is not properly setup to handle that. Generally services are stateless for that reason.

Comment: Thank you. We'll hit it with Jmeter soon so I guess that'll pick up anything we havent thought of.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your setup.  Typically (though not always) java containers will spawn* a thread per request.

*Actually no they won't necessarily spawn one, most servers will work with a thread pool, but the effect is essentially the same.

Some setups, however, will not spawn a thread-per-request, for example if using cometd for long-running requests.  More details on that can be found here: http://cometd.org/book/export/html/31

**Update in response to updated question:**
Jetty will work just fine, unless there are other reasons to move to tomcat?  I like Jetty myself, very low footprint, and I find its xml configs straightforward, but that may just come from 5 years of working with it.

Comment: We're looking to integrate into a third party environment and thought Tomcat would be more widely accepted and supported. Not sure if this assumption is true but it cant hurt to test on another web container. Plus it would allow us to use jMeter

Comment: Wha?  I use JMeter with Jetty all the time.

Comment: Oh I thought it worked best with Tomcat, being a part of the apache family and all.

Comment: JMeter makes http or other requests.  Assuming you have a web ui/webservice interface, you can use jmeter against a .net application.